# Modify select field options using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, selection, appendchild

I am trying to create a Javascript function that will take the value from one select field and then use that to compare a JSON array . If any array elements match the user selected value then the function will add those values to another select field.

**Logic:**

- Activate function using "onchange" HTML attribute
- Get user selected value from select field
- Compare this value to JSON array
- If array value == selected value , append to other select field

**Code:**

```
//this function modifies a select field depending on what value was selected by its predecessor
        function tariffs()
        {   
            //variable selection equals the selected value chosen by the user in that field
            var selection = document.getElementById('tariff_net').options[document.getElementById('tariff_net').selectedIndex].value

            //for loop to go through JSON values to compare with the value chosen by the user
            for(var i = 0; i < values.preset_name.length ; i++)
                {
                    //if the JSON value equals the user selected value
                  if (values.preset_name[i] == selection)
                    {   
                        //append it to the "tariff_name" select field
                        var option = values.preset_name[i];
                        var selectfield = document.getElementById('tariff_name');
                        selectfield.appendChild(option);
                    }
                }


        }
```

Here is a screenshot showing the two select fields (the one on top will affect the bottom select fields options)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNI63.png

[image]

At the moment my code is not working and I am getting a Javascript Error:

> Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMHTMLInputElement.appendChild]
>   [Break On This Error] selectfield.appendChild(option);

I am also wondering how I would be able to make the Javscript refresh the select field of all values and then repopulate it. This would prevent a large accumulation of duplicated options whenever the function is called.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net) showing what you've attempted so far?

Comment: @DavidThomas I could try but the problem is my fields are generated using PHP and so is my JSON

Comment: Then try and see if you can emulate, as closely as possible, with static HTML/JS. It's not ideal, I know, but without seeing what's going on it's difficult to offer help. And, in reproducing the problem without the Ajax, you get, at least, an idea of whereabouts the errors are coming from.

Comment: Your fiddle's still wrong: first select element is auto-closing and there is no "tariff_name" element. Also use "No wrap (head)" in the left side in "Choose framework".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild) takes an element, not a string.  Select options have a constructor to help you:

```
var option = new Option(values.preset_name[i]); //Dom element instead of a string
var selectfield = document.getElementById('tariff_name');
selectfield.appendChild(option);
```

Comment: This solved it thankyou, so what I failed to realise was that anything being passed to the dom needs to be converted to an object/element. 

Makes sense now! Thankyou!

Comment: Any idea how to clear the select field? each time i run this functioN?